# What ensures a human birth in the next life?

Tags: birth, human

What is the minimum merit that needs to be acquired by a human being to ensure he gets a human birth in his next life ?

Any stories/incidents in Puranas etc..that point to this ?

Answer (score 1):

The only answer is good karma. Karmic law is mysterious. One cant say exactly about the karmas needed to be born as a human again.
Well one thing matters a lot is that what u think when you die.
If you die thinking about your dog. It is certain you will be born as a dog in next life. It seems foolish but is actually true.

> Proof:
>   A historic person JadBharat,who  died thinking of his deer and was born as a deer in next life even his karma was good.
>   If we die thinking our wife or children n all we will be born among them in next life.
>   Also our 'wasanas'or desires are carried in our next life. One of my sailor friend who tried past life regression told me that in  his past life he died thinking of to see different parts of world and in his this life he is a sailor on a cargo ship that visits different nations.
>   So good karma and thinking about god while dieing can be a key to be born as human again..

Comment: It's wrong. That Bharata was not the brother of Sri Rama. He is Jada Bharata son of Rishabha.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Do you know about Rishabha he was founder of Jainism, was Jada Bharata part of Jainism since he was son of Rishabha he would have been influenced by his father's Philosophy?

Comment: @Yogi AFAIK Jain people used to believe that Jada Bharata has influence of his father teachings. But they believe that Bharata had became a Jain  monk and obtained renunciation through Kevalya Gyan and hinduism has different version of story.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Oh okay and which story do you think is closer to facts.

Comment: @Yogi For me the story of Vishnu Purana looks more authentic. Because in Jainism Rishabha is mentioned in Adi Purana which is 10th century text. And Vishnu Purana is much more older than that. But it's my view only.

Comment: @Deepeshkumar You should try to add direct link to or quote from scripture, you can find Jada Bharata story from Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) here: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/8. Also, you should not use blockquotes for personal experiences - that makes it looks like you are quoting somebody else. Please also read this answer on meta: [Guidelines for new users answering questions](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/126/2995).

Comment: @Deepeshkumar. Thank you. I was looking for something more specific. I have heard from somewhere (may be from Bhagavadgita) that our Punya Karmas and Papa Karmas get weighed and we go to heavenly planes if we have more punyas and hellish planes if we have more papas. A 50-50 "mishra karma" is what gives us human birth.